# Asp.net encoding

Tags: asp.net, encoding

I have a C#.net console application which reads data from a text file and updates it to the database. The file will have Scandinavian characters and other language characters. This is how I read the file in my app

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
```

but this scrabled the output charcters

I tried  using utf8 to read the file but it was returning characters similar to chinese.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName,Encoding.UTF8))
```

Why is this not working?

Then I tried using the following and its returning the correct characters.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName,Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
```

My question is will the last method help in converting all the characters from different languages or only scandinavain charcters.

I dont have much idea on encoding if someone can explain me how it works. It would be very helpful.

Comment: What is the encoding of your file? I would recommend you using UTF-8 with BOM. If there's no BOM .NET has no way of knowing what how this file is encoded so it will revert to system default.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

About 1252 read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1 . This encoding covers most European languages (with latin script), including but limited to Scandinavian.